# Next.js Middleware No Puede Acceder a las Cookies JWT en Producción con Diferentes Dominios

Tags: cookies, nextjs, middleware

Estoy desarrollando una aplicación con Next.js para el frontend y Node.js con Express.js para el backend. Utilizo un middleware en Next.js para la autenticación basada en JWT. En mi entorno de desarrollo local, donde tanto el frontend como el backend se ejecutan en localhost pero en diferentes puertos (frontend en http://localhost:3000 y backend en http://localhost:8001), todo funciona como se espera.

Sin embargo, cuando se implementa en producción, mi frontend está en https://frontend.com y el backend en https://backend.com:8001. En este entorno, el middleware no puede acceder al token JWT almacenado en las cookies, lo que impide una autenticación y autorización adecuadas.

Aquí está el código relevante de mi middleware de Next.js:

```
// next.js middleware
import { NextResponse } from "next/server";
import { jwtVerify } from "jose";
// ... otros imports ...

const secret = process.env.SECRET;

async function verify(token, secret) {
const { payload } = await jwtVerify(token, new TextEncoder().encode(secret));
return payload;
}

export default async function middleware(request) {
const url = request.url;
const nextUrl = request.nextUrl.clone();
// ... lógica del middleware ...
// Ejemplo de función para verificar acceso
const checkAccess = async (allowedRole) => {
    const jwt = request.cookies.get('token')?.value;
    if (!jwt) {
        nextUrl.pathname = '/';
        return NextResponse.rewrite(nextUrl);
    }
    
    try {
        const verification = await verify(jwt, secret);
        if (verification.Role === allowedRole) {
            return NextResponse.next();
        } else {
            throw new Error("ACCESO DENEGADO");
        }
    } catch (e) {
        // Manejo de errores
        // ...
    }
};

// Verificación de rol
if (url.includes("/dashboard/teacher")) {
    return checkAccess('Teacher');
}
// ... otras verificaciones ...
};

return NextResponse.next();

Esta es la configuración de las cookies para el inicio de sesión en el backend:

function getDomainURL(){
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV){
case ('production'):
return '.frontend.com';
case ('development'):
return 'localhost'
}
}

const COOKIE_OPTIONS = {
httpOnly: true,
path: "/",
sameSite: 'None', // Permitir cookies en solicitudes entre diferentes orígenes
secure: true, // Requerido cuando sameSite es 'None'
domain: getDomainURL()
};

res.setHeader("Set-Cookie", serialize("token", token, COOKIE_OPTIONS));

function getOriginURL(){
switch (process.env.NODE_ENV){
case ('production'):
return 'https://www.frontend.com';
case ('development'):
return 'http://localhost:3000'
}
}

let originURL = getOriginURL()

app.use(cors({
origin: originURL,
credentials: true,
}))
```

El middleware no puede acceder al token en la cookie cuando el backend está en el dominio https://backend.com:8001. Esto impide que el middleware funcione correctamente para proteger las rutas.

¿Cómo puedo configurar mi aplicación de Next.js y/o mi backend para que el middleware pueda acceder correctamente a las cookies a pesar de estar en diferentes dominios?

Cualquier orientación o sugerencia sería muy apreciada. Gracias de antemano."